# Trouble with making part of a textview clickable

Tags: android, textview

```
TextView t;     
TextView t2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    t.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    t=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    t2=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    String s=t.getText().toString();
    t.setText(s, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
    int i=s.indexOf("create one here");
    int i2=i+14;

    Spannable mySpannable =new  SpannableString(t.getText());//(Spannable)t.getText();

    ClickableSpan myClickableSpan = new ClickableSpan()         
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View widget) {
            t2.setText("working");  
        }

    };

    mySpannable.setSpan(myClickableSpan, i, i2 , 
    Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);         
}
```

I have no idea whats going wrong with this code. When I run it, the app crashes on startup

Comment: can you post the stack trace

Comment: please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Allways format Your code and put the error log inside Your question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
t.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
t=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```

`t` is `null` when you try `setMovementMethod`. Put the assignment of `t` first.

Answer (score 0):

Your are trying to use `t` without initializing it.

Move

```
t.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

below

```
t=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```